# How to pass nested data to FlatList react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I have this structure:
[image]

This is chat node, right now it is 3 different chats, every chat has two members. I want to render every chat and pass the data from other user. So when i log in i have this id from firebase : lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93. I want to filter out unnecesary data so i could show profile_picture and username of other user.

So right now i just pass data like this:

```
let allChats = Object.keys(this.state.chats).map(key => key);
    return (
      <ListItems
        navigate={navigate}
        data={allChats}
        // extraData={this.state.usersData}
      />
    );
```

But it only has keys of chats. And result is this:
[image]
I want that in there would be other user Username and profile_picture now there is chat key and react logo.
Full source code of this component: https://pastebin.com/72y5t1g9

Help plz

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a list of `ListItem`s:

```js
const { chats } = this.state;
const chatKeys = Object.keys(chats);
return chatKeys.map(chatKey => (
  <ListItem
    key={chatKey}
    leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: chats[chatKey].profile_picture } }}
    title={chats[chatKey].username}
  />
));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for idea, but how i will filter the data. I now have tempuser and lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93 users data. I always know logged in user ID now its: lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93 so how i need to get tempuser data, (tempuser could be any type of characters)

Comment: Do you need to look up in every key until you find the logged in user? I would need a more explicit example, could you add it to your question?

Comment: I need another user data, i have my ID: lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93  i get it with user token. How do I get another user ID? the another user id now is 'tempuser'. How i need to filter data to access it? I added the pastebin of all source code.